# How to delete non-empty directories in netrw (Vim 8 or Neovim)?

Tags: neovim, netrw, vim8

I try to delete some non-empty folder in netrw by pressing <kbd>Shift d</kbd> and, after press `y`, I got this error:

`(netrw) unable to delete directory {path}`

I already put this variable in my `.config/nvim/init.vim` file and doesn't works: `let g:netrw_localrmdir='rm -r'`

As I read, this variable only works with vim 7.4 and earlier.

Is there a way to delete non-empty directories with netrw in Vim 8+ or Neovim?

My setup:

```
OS: MacOs Catalina
NVIM v0.4.3
```

**EDIT**

My intention is to use as few plugins as possible, but, `netrw` has some other bugs, so U gave up using `netrw` and installed `NERDTree` again.

Answer (score 5):

> There's a way to delete non-empty directories with netrw in vim 8+ or nvim?

You could do
`:!rm -rf directory`

That warning means, you have files still in that directory. So if a file in that directory you want to delete is on the current buffer, you could do this.

`:!rm -rf %:h`

Which deletes the directory of the current file. `%:h` expands to the directory of the current file, and you can even press `<tab>` to have it expand and you can modify the path if you wanted.

---

Another alternative would be, use `R` and just move it to `/tmp` or something which gets deleted automatically by the system, in my case linux.

Comment: But /tmp only gets deleted on a shutdown, right? Or is it cleaned periodically ?

Comment: I think it's on every restart. On WSL though, it never deletes `/tmp` so what I do is just add a script that deletes file older than 1week so something like this: `fd . /tmp --changed-before 1w -H -x rm -rf`. Which gets called every time I open my shell.

Comment: Yeah macOS doesnt seem to delete either (except maybe restarts, tbh im not sure). Clever trick!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble In Mac OS you can move it to `~/.Trash` instead. Then there's an option where you can delete them every 30 days. If you want it sooner, then a script is better.

Comment: How do I map any of these commands to the `D` command in `netrw` though (in Neovim or Vim > 7.4)?

Answer (score 4):

`mf` to mark the directory

`mx` to apply shell command to marked files

```
rm -rf <enter>
```